# How to open the solution physical folder with File Explorer in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I cannot even copy and paste that physical folder in properties window :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Visual Studio solution explorer then this isn't a TFS question at all, and you should remove those tags.  But the answer to your question in VS2008/later is to right-click the solution and select "Open Folder in Windows Explorer."

If you mean opening the folder from the TFS Source Control window: You can't open the server folder with Explorer - your solution is stored in a SQL Database and the files don't exist in that form on the server.  You have to get a local copy (using "Get Latest") and then open that copy in explorer.

Comment: You're right it's not TFS :) But I can't see your menu in VS 2005.

Comment: That menu was introduced in VS2008.  You should be able to copy/paste the folder from the properties window, though... what's stopping you?

Comment: When the path is very lengthy that's not practical :)

Comment: Well, unfortunately it's still your only option :)  Try double-clicking in the field in the properties window; that might auto-select the whole thing.  Alternatively, press Home, then Shift-End to select the whole thing quickly with the keyboard.